# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined w/ Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, use-state

**This is my code,**

```
import React, { useEffect,useState } from "react";
import Box from "../Component/Box/box_indonesia.js";
import "../Component/Box/tabel_indonesia.css";
import axios from 'axios';

const Indonesia = () => {
    const [dataindonesia,setdataindonesia] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get("https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api")
        .then((response) => setdataindonesia(response.data.data));
    }, []);

    return(
        <>
        {dataindonesia.map((item) => {
            return(
                <Box 
                jumlahKasus={item.jumlahKasus} 
                meninggal={item.meninggal}
                sembuh={item.sembuh} 
             />
            );
        })}
    </>
    );
 };
export default Indonesia;
```

**API**

```
enter co{
"perawatan": 84481,
"sembuh": 479202,
"meninggal": 17867,
"jumlahKasus": 581550,
"lastUpdate": 1607299200000,
"perKasus": {
    "json": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/kasus",
    "csv": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/kasus.csv",
    "links": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/kasus/links.csv",
    "old": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/kasus/old"
},
"perProvinsi": {
    "json": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/provinsi",
    "csv": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/provinsi.csv"
},
"perHari": {
    "json": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/harian",
    "csv": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/harian.csv"
},
"wismaAtlet": {
    "json": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/wisma-atlet",
    "karyawan": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/wisma-atlet/karyawan",
    "ruangan": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/wisma-atlet/ruangan",
    "kasur": "https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/wisma-atlet/kasur"
}
```

}

**Why it can't read the property 'map' of my code? I do the same with my other project and it works, can you help me please, I just stuck at there just now, I just learn with the new project of Axios btw, thank u so much for ur help.**

Comment: It's because the data returned from the server - `response.data.data` is not an array, I can't seem to see what it returns from your example.

Comment: `response.data.data` is undefined. Log it and see why. I'd start with `response.data`

Comment: I allready try it, but still error 'TypeError: dataindonesia.map is not a function' :(

Comment: at `then`, instead of update state console.log res `.then(console.log)` to know its structure response